# Error de caracteres en Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo problemas a la hora de ejecutar el siguiente codigo en Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import os, sys
sara1 = '░█▀▀▀█ ─█▀▀█ ░█▀▀█ ─█▀▀█'
sara2 = ' ▀▀▀▄▄ ░█▄▄█ ░█▄▄▀ ░█▄▄█'
sara3 = '░█▄▄▄█ ░█─░█ ░█─░█ ░█─░█'
print (sara1)
print (sara2)
print (sara3)
```

El problema que tengo es que el resultado que obtengo por pantalla es el siguiente:

```
ŠŠ¯¯¯Š -Š¯¯Š ŠŠ¯¯Š -Š¯¯Š
 ¯¯¯__ ŠŠ__Š ŠŠ__¯ ŠŠ__Š
ŠŠ___Š ŠŠ-ŠŠ ŠŠ-ŠŠ ŠŠ-ŠŠ
```

¿Qué podría hacer para que se muestre correctamente?

Pd: para los curiosos es una muestra el nombre que agregue.

Comment: Pones en el comentario de la cabecera que el encoding del fichero es iso-8859-15. Debes verificar que (a) tu editor realmente está guardándolo en ese formato y (b) la terminal en la que ejecutas el programa usa el _encoding_ que python está suponiendo para la misma (que puedes averiguar con un `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`. En mi ordenador en que el editor guarda en UTF-8, y la terminal también soporta UTF-8, me funciona sin más que quitar el comentario del `coding` (pues python3 supone los fuentes en utf8 por defecto)

Answer (score 3):

La codificación que estás utilizando, la ISO 8859-15, más conocida como Latin-9, sólo dispone de 256 caracteres; y esos que intentas imprimir no están entre ellos. Creo que la solución es la que apunta el compañero en el comentario: utilizar la UTF-8.

Podría quedar así:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
sara1 = '░█▀▀▀█ ─█▀▀█ ░█▀▀█ ─█▀▀█'
sara2 = ' ▀▀▀▄▄ ░█▄▄█ ░█▄▄▀ ░█▄▄█'
sara3 = '░█▄▄▄█ ░█─░█ ░█─░█ ░█─░█'
print (sara1)
print (sara2)
print (sara3)
```

Puedes ver los caracteres del estándar Latin 9 [en este enlace](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/latin9.html)

Comment: Bien visto! No había caido yo en la cuenta de que los caracteres usados no están en esa tabla, sino en la [CP-850](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_850) y por supuesto también en Unicode, razón por la que funciona con utf-8.

Comment: File "logos.py", line 4
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @JuanVial por el shebang entiendo que utilizas Linux, ¿es correcto? y si es así, ¿qué editor o IDE usas?

Comment: @Arg0s No utilizo linux, utilizo Windows, y todo desde el editor de notas, osea notepad.

Comment: @JuanVial Ah! Puede deberse a que el bloc de notas de Windows usa ANSI como codificación por defecto. Has probado a guardar el texto como UTF-8?. Copiando el código -> Pegarlo en el Notepad -> Guardar Como -> Seleccionar "UTF-8" en el combobox de "Codificación" -> Pulsar "Guardar" y ejecutándolo debería funcionar